# Pandas Change column date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have column in pandas dataframe as follows:

```
0    2018-04-06
1    2018-04-06
2    2018-04-09
3    2018-04-19
4    2018-04-19
5    2018-04-17
```

I want to convert this column into yyyy/mm/dd for which I have coaded as follows:

```
def change_date_format(x):
    if x != 'nan' and x != '' and x != ' ' and x != 0:
        x = parse(x, dayfirst=True).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return x
    else:
        return ''

read4['Column Name'] = read4['Column Name'].apply(lambda x : change_date_format(x)  )
```

But it's convert as follows:

```
2018-06-04
2018-06-04
2018-09-04
2018-04-19
2018-04-19
2018-04-17
```

which ideally should be :

```
2018-04-06
2018-04-06
2018-04-09
2018-04-19
2018-04-19
2018-04-17
```

How do I force it do work as above. Basically it should consider the input also and depends on that it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert not parseable values to `NaT`, then [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and last [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
read4['Column Name'] = (pd.to_datetime(read4['Column Name'], errors='coerce')
                          .dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                          .replace('NaT', ''))
  Column Name
0  2018-04-06
1  2018-04-06
2  2018-04-09
3  2018-04-19
4  2018-04-19
5  2018-04-17
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170987/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-pandas-change-column-date-format).

Comment: brother can I provide multiple `unit` for `to_datetime` as I need to convert `np.int64` type column with different range of integer.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - Can you explain more? Maybe the best create new question with sample data and excpected output.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to set your `dayfirst` flag to `False`?

```
x = parse(x, dayfirst=False).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: I know this works fine but only for this scenario not for other.